# Having difficulty merging 2 streaming datasets to one dataset

Tags: powerbi, dax, business-intelligence

How can I merge 2 streaming datasets from 2 different workspaces in Power BI Desktop to make it into 1 data set containing all tables of the 2 streaming datasets.

I tried it through Powery Query but failed to make it work. Looking for any new ideas to try.  Also Chat GPT said it possible can't be done but that's also knowledge from 2021 so hoping there has been new insights since then. Thanks mates!!

Answer (score 0):

In a new Power BI, don't import or use Power Query, instead go to `OneLake data hub` in the Home ribbon and select `Power BI datasets`. Here you can connect to one dataset via Live Connection. Once done, repeat the process to add another dataset.